# MySQL Select row where text field contains number bigger than X

Tags: mysql, select, find-in-set

I have a text column ( `MISCDATA` ) in a database wich contains multiple numeric values and string values, separated by comas and semicolons. Is there a way to build a query to select only the rows where `MISCDATA` contains a number bigger than 50 (example)?

I thought of the use of FIND_IN_SET() but I can't place it in the correct context.

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('NUMBER BIGGER THAN 50', MISCDATA);
```

I don't know if I explained myself correctly, anyhow all help will be apreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Some example data from the field:

```
MA, 22; HR, 42; HG, 29; JW, 44; MI, 76; GJ, 56;
```

The above example should be listed by the SELECT because it contains 2 numbers bigger than 50 (MI and GJ).

Comment: If you're in the position to change the database design, by all means do it. Never store multiple values in one column. Read about normalization.

Comment: I can imagine such solution. But it is near senseless. You have very clear intention - to work with separate values. So store them as separate entities. 1:many relation (so additional table) must be applied for your database design.

Comment: I am not in the position to do that. I am barely a PHP consultant. Also, I wouldn't know to what other type I would change it to.

Comment: Is each numeric value exactly two digits?  For example, is "MA, 125" a possible value?  How about "MA, 6"?

Comment: The values are from 0 to 99. Never bigger than 99. And also, the number could not exist, leaving the field like "GJ, ;"

Answer (score -1):

A solution would be to use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) :

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE REGEXP '@yourRegexToWrite'.
```

The job is to write a good regex...

Comment: A helpful answer would include the regular expression that solves the questioner's problem.  Also, the SQL in this answer is not good syntax: there's no column name in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Well actually, I cannot leave a comment to this post, I could only post an answer. As you say, this is not a complete answer, but maybe the way to get it. I thought this would help a little...